# MongoDB: Grouping and counting elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a list of books. I would like to get the number of genres that the authors wrote, also I would like to add to the results which are those genres. My database looks like this:

```
{"_id": ObjectID("1), "title": "Harry Potter", "year": NumberInt(2000), "author": "JK. Rowling", 
"genres": "Fantasy"}, 
"_id": ObjectID("2"), "title": "Harry Potter 99", "year": NumberInt(2020), "author": "JK. Rowling", 
"genres": "Drama"}, "_id": ObjectID("2"), "title": "Harry Potter", "year": NumberInt(2000), "author": "JK. Rowling", 
"genres": "Drama"}, {...}
```

So, my code so far looks like this:

```
phase1 = {$group : {"_id" : "$author"}, "countgenres" : {$sum : 1}}
phase2 = {$addFields : "genres"}}
phase3 = {$sort : {"numgenres" : -1}}

steps = [phase1, phase2, phase3]
db.database.aggregate(steps)
```

This is not working for me, so I would like if someone could help me to write a correct code to do this. The result should look like this:

```
{

"_id" : "JK. Rowling",

"countgenres" : 4,

"genres" : [
"Fantasy",
"Drama"

]
}
```

I've posted a similar question one hour ago but I've made a mistake in the database, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, with the input example the output should has only 2 genres, right?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, fixed!

Comment: I've updated my answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1t3XCMHhnYc) query where I have added a new author to check the sort too.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "author": "JK. Rowling"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$genres"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$author",
      "genres": {
        "$addToSet": "$genres"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "numgenres": {
        "$size": "$genres"
      },
      "genres": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "numgenres": -1
    }
  }
])
```

The query first `$unwind` to separate the values from `genres` and uses `$addToSet` to avoid repeat values. Then use `$project` to get the array size.

Comment: Thanks! But with this I get a lot of authors together, I would like to get one author at a time.

Comment: Updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, if you only want one author, why do you try to sort by `numgenres`? There will be always only one document result, right?

Comment: Yes, I would like that in each author you can see the number of genres that they wrote. How could I sort it by "numgenres"?

Comment: But, if you want search only from one author, you will get only one document with the number of `numgenres` for the specific author. That's right? So,  if there is only one result, what do you want to order?

Comment: If you don't use the stage `{ "$match": { "author": "JK. Rowling" } }`, then, a lot of authors are found. And how exists more than one result, then it make sense the order.

Comment: I would like to see all the authors, with the genres (and the number of genres) that they wrote. Ordered from more genrer written to less. With your answer I get a lot of authors grouped. For example, if author A, author B and author C, wrote "Drama", "Comedy" and "War", they group the three in one result. I would like the result for each author. I hope I'm making myself clear... Thanks!